# Can't change drive letter to "D:"

Tags: windows-8, drive-letter

I've just made a clean install of Windows 8 on an SSD drive. I also have another drive which I want to use as D:. But when I try to assign a drive letter I can only choose A, B, I, J and so on to Z. My optical drive got J after the installation.

[image: Assign drive letters]

I've found something in the registry which could explain the missing drive letters, but I don't exactly know what it means.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change flyttbar disk letter "D".

[image]

Comment: At first I wondered what was up with this answer, but then I noticed the "Disk 2" in the disk management screenshot. Good eyeball!

Comment: Funny. I didn't notice that :). That must be all those memory card slots. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same solution. I partitioned my C: drive, and I wanted to make the new partition D:, but D: wasn't on the drop-down list. I had to scroll down the list of drives in the bottom half of the window to see that the DVD drive was D:, and E-H were reserved for removable media. I changed E: to K:, D: to E:, and changed partition 2 of disc 0 to D:. Simple.

Comment: Had to insert a disc for the dvd drive using D to appear in the list - then I could change it.